# Which famous people can be identified in Death Becomes Her?

Tags: character-identification, death-becomes-her

In *Death Becomes Her*, there is a party towards the end where a number of famous celebrities can be seen. I spotted Elvis, Marilyn Monroe, Andy Warhol, Morrison, James Dean, and there was verbal reference to (I believe) Greta Garbo. Are there any other celebrities that I missed?

Comment: The [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onvXE.png) mentions a few others, Marilyn Monroe, Elvis and Andy Warhol as well as Dick Clarke and George Hamilton.

Comment: IMDB doesn't mention any others than the ones you've mentioned; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104070/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast

Comment: I'm 100% sure this has been asked before. Oh wait, maybe on Movies.

Comment: Wasn't Dick Clark still publicly alive when that movie came out?  Same with George Hamilton.

Answer (score 2):

I’m pretty sure Dick Clarke and George Hamilton aren’t in the film as there is no evidence via IMDb. I’m pretty sure there are just 6: Andy Warhol, Greta Garbo, Marilyn Monroe, Elvis Presley, Jim Morrison and James Dean. The blonde girl the Jim Morrison was with at the pool scene wasn’t a celebrity that is thought dead; she was just a guest at the party who was with him.

Comment: Could you [edit] in any of your evidence to back this up? That said for your first point those could be in the film and just uncredited.